# Order of Procedure for Select statement with Where Clause and other operators

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the table I'm working off:

```
CREATE TABLE Person 
(
    IdNo number (3),
    Name VARCHAR2(30), 
    Gender VARCHAR2(3), 
    QtyA number (3),
    QtyB number (3),
    Primary Key (IdNo)
);

INSERT INTO Person (IdNo, Name, Gender, QtyA, QtyB)
VALUES (23,'Johnny Storm','M',10,10);

INSERT INTO Person (IdNo, Name, Gender, QtyA, QtyB)
VALUES (46,'Eric Twinge ','M',7,4);

INSERT INTO Person (IdNo, Name, Gender, QtyA, QtyB)
VALUES (17,'Diana Prince ','F',4,7);

INSERT INTO Person (IdNo, Name, Gender, QtyA, QtyB) 
VALUES (28,'Susan Storm ','F',1,3);

INSERT INTO Person (IdNo, Name, Gender, QtyA, QtyB) 
VALUES (134,'Dick Grayson ','m',6,2);

INSERT INTO Person (IdNo, Name, Gender, QtyA, QtyB) 
VALUES (5,'Barbara Gordon ','F',8,7);

INSERT INTO Person (IdNo, Name, Gender, QtyA, QtyB) 
VALUES (24,'Selina Kyle ','F',4,0);

INSERT INTO Person (IdNo, Name, Gender, QtyA, QtyB)
VALUES (78,'Rick Hunt ','M',NULL,NULL);

INSERT INTO Person (IdNo, Name, Gender, QtyA, QtyB) 
VALUES (81,'Ted Howler ','M',6,6);

INSERT INTO Person (IdNo, Name, Gender, QtyA, QtyB)
VALUES (89,'Sonita Marks ','F',3,6);
    
INSERT INTO Person (IdNo, Name, Gender, QtyA, QtyB)
VALUES (2,'Dave Orkle ','M',2,4);
```

From this order of procedure that was provided in class:

1. Parentheses
2. */
3. +-
4. = <= >= < >
5. IS
6. Between
7. NOT
8. AND
9. OR

I have to work out how many rows of the following statement with show up:

```
SELECT Name FROM person
WHERE gender = 'F' OR gender = 'M'
AND QtyA+QtyB < 5
```

Is this statement read in this order:

1. QtyA+QtyB
2. QtyA+QtyB < 5
3. gender = 'F'
4. gender = 'M'
5. gender = 'M' AND QtyA+QtyB < 5
6. gender = 'F' OR gender = 'M'

My logic that is probably wrong is:

1. Since no parentheses it does the addition first - `QtyA+QtyB`
2. Then it does `<` operator as it's the next one on that list given to me `< 5`.
3. Then it does the `=` which is gender = 'F'
4. Then `gender = 'M'` as it's the next equal
5. Then it does the `AND` operator so `gender = 'M' AND QtyA+QtyB`
6. Finally it does the `OR` operator then `gender = 'F' OR gender = 'M'`

So 0 rows will show up after step 5

The next test apparently has a large section where you have to read Select statements and find how many rows will show from them without typing anything in and I feel like I'm doing this completely wrong, but I came up with 0 which is what the select statement gave me when I type it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply parentheses.  The query as written is expressing:

```
WHERE (gender = 'F') OR
       (gender = 'M' AND (QtyA + QtyB) < 5)
```

That is because `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.  Then arithmetic operations are going to be evaluated before comparisons.

Comment: I just realised why nothing I did made sense. I had a space after the M and F in the insert statement so when I was doing the select statement without the space I couldn't find anything. I edited it now and you're answer makes everything easier to understand Thanks!